# Tour of Go rot13Reader buffer not being updated after Read function finishes

Tags: go

Here is my implementation of the exercise using strings.Map (the rot13 function is straight out of golang's docs). The issue is that the buffer does not seem to be modified after the Read function returns. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (reader *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    rot13 := func(r rune) rune {
        switch {
        case r >= 'A' && r <= 'Z':
            return 'A' + (r-'A'+13)%26
        case r >= 'a' && r <= 'z':
            return 'a' + (r-'a'+13)%26
        }
        return r
    }
    n, err := reader.r.Read(b)
    result := []byte(strings.Map(rot13, string(b)))
    b = []byte(result)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

and the output:

```
You cracked the code!
Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!You cracked the code!
```

Clearly the buffer has been modified in the Read function, but it does not seem to be the case after it returns. If I were to comment out the `fmt.Println(string(b))`, the output would just be:

```
Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!
```

Is there something quirky about Readers and Writers that I should know about?

Comment: Nope. You're printing it from `Read` (right before the `return`) and again in `main` (you're copying the read bytes to stdout).

Comment: The Read method does not modify the caller's slice.

Comment: @CeriseLimón what do you mean? Is the line `b = []byte(result)` not modifying the buffer, b?

Comment: @Adrian can you clarify what you are trying to say? I know I am printing it from Read, that print statement is for debugging purposes to see if the method is modifying the buffer, b, or not, which from the output, it looks like it is (at least inside the Read method).

Comment: The assignment changes local variable b. It does not modify the backing array of the caller’s slice.  If this does not make sense, then jump to the tour pages about slices. The simple solution is to read in to the caller’s slice, rotate bytes in that slice and return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Go, all arguments are passed by value, as if by assignment to the parameter or receiver (a shallow copy).

In Go, a slice is implemented as

```
type slice struct {
    array unsafe.Pointer
    len   int
    cap   int
}
```

When the slice is passed by value, after you return, you will not see any changes you make to the copy of the `struct` fields. You will only see any changes to elements of the underlying array.

---

In your case, you overwrite `b` (`array`, `cap`, `len`), a copy.

```
b = []byte(result)
```

The copy is is discarded when you return.

---

What you want to do is change elements of `b`'s `array`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func rot13(b byte) byte {
    switch {
    case b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z':
        return 'A' + (b-'A'+13)%26
    case b >= 'a' && b <= 'z':
        return 'a' + (b-'a'+13)%26
    }
    return b
}

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (reader *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := reader.r.Read(b)
    b = b[:n]
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = rot13(b[i])
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0LDYmzrrgty

Output:

```
You cracked the code!
```

---

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: Yea I realized my silly mistake after reading the comment from @CeriseLimón. Finding it weird that Go decided to use return parameters instead of just returning the slice.

Answer (score -1):

I am not too sure, so please take the below with between a few grains to several pounds of salt.

First you should add an error check as early as possible:

```golang
n, err := reader.r.Read(b)
if err != nil && err == io.EOF {
    fmt.Printf("\n%s, %d bytes read", err, n)
    return n, err
}
```

With this added, the output is the one you would expect:

```
You cracked the code!
Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!
EOF, 0 bytes read
```

The reason here is that a reader is supposed to return io.EOF in case there is nothing to read any more.

So why did you experience said strange behavior? A quick look in the source code of `io.Copy` reveals that [`b` is allocated once and reused](https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12796:12856#L390). But since `b` was not modified (no bytes were read) and you accessed it for reading from it, it still held the same values as before. I would argue that the underlying `io.Reader` should clear `b` in case nothing is read, as per principle of least surprise, though.

Comment: This still doesn't work as intended. If I were to add that error check and comment out the `fmt.Println(string(b))` line, I wouldn't see the decoded message. Also, I would expect that the EOF error would already come from the strings Reader, which is passed to the caller anyways from the last return. Or is it just good practice for the wrapper to also handle the EOF error?